# Why is BIM360 Issues API call responding with 'user not found' from Forge/APS?

Tags: oauth, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

2 problems to solve in this thread:

1. BIM360 Issues API call is not working when it's been working for months
2. API calls with 3-legged token returns empty `data`, while with 2-legged token returns like normal.

Context: I have a pipeline that runs everyday and [call Issues API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/) to retrieve project issues and all relevant data such as project info and issues_type. This has been running smoothly for a year now. (Yes, I do know that issues/v1 is recently deprecated)

On Feb. 6th, 2023,  I encountered a response when using the 3-legged-token to call GET /issues (v1 and v2):

```json
{
    "title": "User not found",
    "details": "user not found",
    "metadata": {}
}
```

To debug, I tried running each API call in the procedure, by following this tutorial to
GET /hubs and GET /containerID https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/issuesv2/retrieve-container-id/.

I got this when I call GET /hubs:

```json
GET /project/v1/hubs
Authorization: "Bearer <3-legged token>"

{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs"
        }
    },
    "data": [], <---- Uh oh
    "meta": {
        "warnings": [
            {
                "Id": null,
                "HttpStatusCode": "403",
                "ErrorCode": "BIM360DM_ERROR",
                "Title": "Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM EMEA.",
                "Detail": "You don't have permission to access this API",
                "AboutLink": null,
                "Source": null,
                "meta": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The `meta.warnings` field with an error code is not uncommon.

I tried calling GET /hubs again but **with the 2-legged token**:

```json
GET /project/v1/hubs

{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/"
        }
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "hubs",
            "id": "<hidden>",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "User Hub",
                "extension": {
                    "type": "hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account-1.0"
                    },
                    "data": {}
                },
                "region": "US"
            },
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/<hidden>"
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "projects": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/<hidden>/projects"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "warnings": [
            {
                "Id": null,
                "HttpStatusCode": "403",
                "ErrorCode": "BIM360DM_ERROR",
                "Title": "Unable to get hubs from BIM360DM EMEA.",
                "Detail": "You don't have permission to access this API",
                "AboutLink": null,
                "Source": null,
                "meta": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice that :

- With 3-legged token `data` returns `[]`.
- With 2-legged token `data` returns a hub object.

I tried refreshing token and checking permissions to BIM360, but nothing has changed.

TL;DR AutoDesk deprecated the Issues API, but then the API call to GET /hubs with 3-legged token returns `[]`, but with 2-legged token returns desired hub-object.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Issue API (v1, v2) does not support 2-legged token. GET:Hubs , GE:"Projects etc. are Data Management API which support 2-legged token or 3-legged token.

In your test, it also failed with 3-legged token when GET:Hubs. When using Issue API, it shows [User not found]. I highly suspected this user has been removed from the BIM360 hub now or its status is abnormal. Could you  check if the user is available in the hub and the project? Also test with other users if your code could work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created a new user and manually added their permissions for each project, and was successful in using the Issue API again.
It seems the issue lies with the "user" didn't have proper permissions.